# Two named "Unique" item effects

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that in League of Legends, if I try to have two items which are both unique with the same effect, that only the earlier purchased item's effect applies. (http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Unique)

My question is in regards to stacking named Unique items with different effects.

Titanic Hydra and Ravenous Hydra both have "UNIQUE - Cleave" effects  but each Cleave effect does something different.

Does this mean that both Hydra's effect will be applied or will the same rule of which came first apply?

Comment: Found a post from 3 months ago:
http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/gameplay-balance/JjEKvjGf-ravenous-hydra-and-titanic-hydra-question

No definitive answers.  Might just need to build it in 1 vs 3 bot games and test it out.

Comment: It won't stack - except it is a bug atm. Same with Iceborn Gauntlet and Lich Bane, also not exactly the same effect. If it would be different you wouldn't be the first recognizing this and someone would have purchased both items at the same time, what I have never seen.

Comment: I think it switches between the two effects (in case of the two "hydras")

Comment: Hmm, ironically, based on the "duplicate" question, I suspect some effects DO stack, just like the Spellblade effect.  The question is what effects stacks, and whether the two AoE effects are different or the same.  Having two AoE on-hit triggers could be pretty broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like h0ch5tr4355 said: it doesn't stack. Just like Iceborn Gauntlet, Lichbane, Sheen, TriForce or any jungle item with Runeglaive. All those unique passives are called spellblade and do something different. But only one of them will trigger.

It's probably for balancing purposes. Imagine a Nasus with both Iceborn and TriForce hitting you. Or a Riven/Darius with both Ravenous and Titanic Hydra.

And I still haven't figured out why some junglers have a Runeglaive and Lichbane as recommended core items.

Comment: The builds are recommended, not full builds. Runeglaive compared to Lich Bane is a BAD item. It is however cheap. It costs 400 Gold (1200 + 850) instead of 3000 Gold. Lich Bane provides only a boost in damage, while nice is only useful for certain situations, while runeglaive procs an AoE on jungle camps and provides mana sustain which is much appreciated. Later in the game when Killing camps can be done easily it's not needed anymore and Lich Bane is much more effective as a Sheen Item

Comment: I suppose switching it out for Lich Bane late game works. Then again, using Diana's shield and the Runeglaive to instantly clear a camp after 50 minutes is pretty neat.

Comment: Yes, there's also that factor, insted of going for Morello/Chalice on Diana you can keep the runeglaive and that allows you for some sustain and good clear (essentially you can get a lot of mana if you take 5 seconds to go to a camp), and then you can get more AP

Answer (score 2):

This might also clarify a bit more about the unique effect.

**unique** :
 Will only work for the first item, if you buy two of the same items 
**unique - [name]** :
 Will only work for the first item you bought with that same unique name (even if skill do different things)
**unique aura** :
 You can only get an aura bonus one, even if you are near to allies with the same aura giving item.

Comment: If you and an ally both have Banner of Command(or any other item with an aura buff) you get the buff twice. Once from yourself and once from your ally. All other allies will only get the buff once.